# sharing clojurescript atom between different js files (in different pages) on node js

Tags: node.js, clojurescript

I'm using node-webkit with clojurescript to make my desktop app, and I met a problem when I tried to share an atom between multiple windows(with different js file including.)

When I define a node-global-variable as `(set! js/global.foo (atom bar))`, it does create a global variable as an atom, but when I try to call reset!/swap! on the atom through another js file in another window, it crashes, telling me that swap!/reset! method not supported on type atom.

And I tried another way, I defined an atom using `(def foo (atom bar))`, and `(set! js/global.baz foo)` , then I moved all swap!/reset! functions to the js which I defined the foo, and other js files only reads js/global.baz without any attemption to write it...then I found that as bar is reset. the value of global.baz doesn't change.

I searched a lot on these without getting any information about it, it seems that few people are using node-global-variables in cljs.

I need some help....thanks

Comment: It may have to do with having two js environments (browser and node). I've had problems in the past because clojurescript relies on thing like instanceof that doesn't work across boundaries since the js and cljs primitives are different on each vm so it makes pretty hard interoperating data structures between the browser and the node code. This is a nightmare both to debug and solve/work around, I hope this gives you some ideas to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To persist data between pages you may use [one of persistence options](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app). I think [Storage-Atom](https://github.com/alandipert/storage-atom) is well suited for your needs.